# ssh connection sporadically hangs

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

Whenever I ssh to elsewhere, the connection is fine for 1-10 minutes, then hangs: no error messages, just stops accepting input.  I can exit (`CR`-`~`-`.`) but that's it.  I can't find anything suspicious in my logs, or on the server I'm connecting to.  Running `ssh -vvv` doesn't produce any messages around the time of disconnection, and connecting to `sshd -dd` doesn't say anything then either.  I don't think it's a timeout, since it happens at irregular intervals: sometimes 1 minute, sometimes 10. I can tell exactly when it disconnects by running `while $(sleep 1); do date; done` on the remote computer.

Other notes:

- All ssh connections I have running at once hang at the same time.
- `tcpdump` shows me that when it hangs, it also stops sending or receiving packets.
- `netstat` says that the connection is still ESTABLISHED, however.
- It sounds a lot like [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/519195/debugging-clogged-tcp-connections), but setting `ServerAliveInterval` to e.g. 30 instead results in the connection ending with `Timeout, server not responding.`
- I'm running openssh 1:6.7p1-2 in Debian sid.

This may well be a problem with connectivity, not just ssh, but I'm trying to get debugging information, somehow.

How can I debug this?

Comment: this sound like a firewall/router is blocking you.

Comment: is there any way to tell?

Comment: Can you run `tcpdump` on the server ? This might give a clue about what's happening. I'd run it inside a [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) session and detach it so it doesn't interfere / isn't affected by disconnects.

Comment: We had a similar problem which turned out to be caused by routing problems on a device with multiple VLANs and a physical connection.